# findViewById doesn't see button in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a TabLayout Activity that contains 3 fragments, each of which has buttons.
I'm trying to get a button from one of the fragments in this Activity, but I'm getting the error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference.
How can I get a button from a TabLayout fragment and assign it to change Activity when clicked?

My TabLayout class:

```
public class SecondPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tl;
    ViewPager2 vp2;
    PagerAdapter pa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_page);

        tl = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_spage);
        vp2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager_spage);
        pa = new PagerAdapter(this);
        vp2.setAdapter(pa);
        //there I try to get Button via Button b = findViewById(R.id.fbtn); and get an error
        //fbtn is in the fragment Basic


        tl.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                vp2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Fragment class:

```
public class Basic extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_basic, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to get the fragment instance first, then you can access to its views

Comment: @Walid Please, don't give someone horrible advice. Generally, you should never access views of a fragment from activity.

Comment: I know, I just pointed out why it's not working. It's more a hint than an answer or an advice. and that's why I posted it as comment and not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your are trying to access the button instance that is contained inside the Fragmen xml from your Activity xml.

To fix this, you should go to your `FragmentBasic` and after `onCreateView` is finished (inside `onViewcreated`) find the button and do the action you need.

To communicate between a fragment and an activity you can use a shared viewmodel

Please see

> https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate